# Using IntStream to access array of objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an array of RGB objects, holding an R value, G value, and B value, which combine to represent a color. I need to use an `IntStream` in order to run through the elements of the array and do a computation on each of them. How can I use the IntStream to do this?

My array was defined as such:

```
RGB[] pixels;
```

With the RGB class defined as such:

```
class RGB {
  public int R, G, B;

  RGB(int r, int g, int b) {
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;
  }
}
```

The provided hint says to use `IntStream.range()` to give me a stream of indices.

Answer (score 1):

You could stream the array indexes:

```
IntStream.range(0, pixels.length)
         .map(i -> someCalculationOn(i, pixels[i]));
```

But if you don't need the index in `someCalculation`, streaming the array itself may be better:

```
Arrays.stream(pixels).map(rgb -> someCalculationOn(rgb));
```